# Get InstanceId from ec2.json file

Tags: json, bash, amazon-web-services, jq

how do I get InstanceId value?
Note - I'm doing this on Win10

I tried

```
jq '.Instances[] .InstanceId[]' ec2.json
```

but I get

```
Error - jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
'.Instances[]
jq: 1 compile error
```

The data is given below:

```
{
    "Groups": [],
    "Instances": [
        {
            "AmiLaunchIndex": 0,
            "ImageId": "ami-0c1a7f89451184c8b",
            "InstanceId": "i-0144deb73abecac7c",
            "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
            "KeyName": "SaasPectKeyPair",
            "LaunchTime": "2021-06-08T14:22:47+00:00",
            "Monitoring": {
                "State": "disabled"
            },
            "Placement": {
                "AvailabilityZone": "ap-south-1b",
                "GroupName": "",
                "Tenancy": "default"
            },
            "PrivateDnsName": "ip-172-31-9-94.ap-south-1.compute.internal",
            "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.9.94",
            "ProductCodes": [],
            "PublicDnsName": "",
            "State": {
                "Code": 0,
                "Name": "pending"
            },
            "StateTransitionReason": "",
            "SubnetId": "subnet-b3134aff",
            "VpcId": "vpc-210ccf4a",
            "Architecture": "x86_64",
            "BlockDeviceMappings": [],
            "ClientToken": "7b867508-3a09-4fb5-ab54-9ef763417995",
            "EbsOptimized": false,
            "EnaSupport": true,
            "Hypervisor": "xen",
            "NetworkInterfaces": [
                {
                    "Attachment": {
                        "AttachTime": "2021-06-08T14:22:47+00:00",
                        "AttachmentId": "eni-attach-01c465a1559542bf5",
                        "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                        "DeviceIndex": 0,
                        "Status": "attaching",
                        "NetworkCardIndex": 0
                    },
                    "Description": "",
                    "Groups": [
                        {
                            "GroupName": "default",
                            "GroupId": "sg-04472279"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Ipv6Addresses": [],
                    "MacAddress": "0a:d4:9d:f4:48:a2",
                    "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-0d2272b6397ad6cf3",
                    "OwnerId": "891999723090",
                    "PrivateDnsName": "ip-172-31-9-94.ap-south-1.compute.internal",
                    "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.9.94",
                    "PrivateIpAddresses": [
                        {
                            "Primary": true,
                            "PrivateDnsName": "ip-172-31-9-94.ap-south-1.compute.internal",
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.9.94"
                        }
                    ],
                    "SourceDestCheck": true,
                    "Status": "in-use",
                    "SubnetId": "subnet-b3134aff",
                    "VpcId": "vpc-210ccf4a",
                    "InterfaceType": "interface"
                }
            ],
            "RootDeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
            "RootDeviceType": "ebs",
            "SecurityGroups": [
                {
                    "GroupName": "default",
                    "GroupId": "sg-04472279"
                }
            ],
            "SourceDestCheck": true,
            "StateReason": {
                "Code": "pending",
                "Message": "pending"
            },
            "VirtualizationType": "hvm",
            "CpuOptions": {
                "CoreCount": 1,
                "ThreadsPerCore": 1
            },
            "CapacityReservationSpecification": {
                "CapacityReservationPreference": "open"
            },
            "MetadataOptions": {
                "State": "pending",
                "HttpTokens": "optional",
                "HttpPutResponseHopLimit": 1,
                "HttpEndpoint": "enabled"
            },
            "EnclaveOptions": {
                "Enabled": false
            }
        }
    ],
    "OwnerId": "891999723090",
    "ReservationId": "r-03c1c9762da6ec46b"
}
```

Also, can you please tell me if the commands are correct, it will be very helpful.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Create EC2 instance
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-0c1a7f89451184c8b --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --region ap-south-1 --key-name KeyPair --security-group-ids sg-04472279 --subnet-id subnet-b3134aff > 
ec2.json
#Create a tag for EC2 instance
aws ec2 create-tags --resources i-0626755e35fd0b29d --tags Key=Name,Value=Adam

#S3
aws s3 ls
#SSH
ssh -i "KeyPair.pem" ubuntu@ec2-13-232-137-231.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com -y

#Install Apache Web Server and change Index file
sudo apt update -y
sudo apt install apache2 -y
sudo ufw allow 'Apache' 
sudo systemctl restart apache2
sudo cat /var/www/html/index.html <<- _EOF_
    <html>
    <body>
    <h1>Welcome To Index Page</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
_EOF_

#Stop EC2 instance
#aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids i-0626755e35fd0b29d
#Stat EC2 instance
#aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-0626755e35fd0b29d
#Terminate EC2 instance
#aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids i-0626755e35fd0b29d
```

Comment: Try: `jq ".Instances[].InstanceId" < ec2.json`. Note: you may also be able to use the awscli in-built filtering e.g. `aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId"`

Comment: There are many similar questions you could browse for the answers you need: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22704831/7939871

Comment: Thank you @LéaGris, I tried googling and the best result is shown above with error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
jq '.Instances[].InstanceId' ec2.json
```